# Free Text search in Azure Function App - Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-functions

For example I have this string "CTASK0220892", I want to search this in Application Insights for Azure Function App.

What would be the query to search this string?

[image]

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: For example I have this string "CTASK0220892", I want to search this in Application Insights for Azure Function App

Comment: @RakeshKumar, if the answer works, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks. And also please let me know if you still have more issues about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which method you're using to send the string "CTASK0220892" to application insights.

As an example, if you're using `ILogger.LogInformation` method, like below:

```
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            //use ILogger.LogInformation method to send the string to application insights.
            log.LogInformation("CTASK0220892");
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
```

Then in application insights, you can find this string in the `trace` table. Nav to azure portal -> your application insights which is connected to the azure function -> Logs, then use the query below:

```
traces 
| where  message contains "CTASK0220892"
```

Note that: there're many operators besides the **contains** operator, like **==**, **!=**,**startswith** etc. Please use the proper operator as per your need.

Here is the test result:

[image]